# How are BLKID 's Assigned?

Tags: linux, blkid

Suppose I have a situation like I have installed `/etc` and `/boot` in two separate partition which belongs to an **USB device** , and the rest of the system `/` and `/home` in the HDD. Now my question is I need to statically route the USB device in my `fstab` , but the problem is there is no certainty that the USB will always take say `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/sdc` , so my approach would be to use `BLKID`.

Here I am confused as to whether the BLKID of a particular Hardware Device ( With a static Hardware ID) always the same? if not what is the work around in the situation?

How are BLKID's Assigned ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An article modestly called *[UUIDs and Linux: Everything you ever need to know](http://liquidat.wordpress.com/2013/03/13/uuids-and-linux-everything-you-ever-need-to-know/)* states that UUID's of disk devices are stored in superblocks, so they are persistent and can be used in /etc/fstab (in place of /dev device references).  An example entry in fstab might look like

```
UUID=8ec0b48f-a4b8-4ca8-bc27-40984b38b2a7 none  swap  sw   0
```

If you want to change the UUID of an ext2 partition, `tune2fs` (for example) provides the means.  Eg:

```
tune2fs -U new_uuid /dev/sda43
```

Also see the `blkid` man page and to see a list of disk devices organized by UUID, say `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid`.